# Why does content disappear for logged in users?

Tags: views

I have two examples of this. One, I'm using the Umami demo profile, and the pre-header language selector disappears for the logged-in user. I would like the language selector to be visible at all times.

Two, I created a view that shows published articles tagged (1) current issue, (2) sketches. This view works as intended for anonymous users, but the view renders nothing for logged-in users.

[image]

What setting do I change to make this view available at all times?

Answer (score 1):

The Views Admin UI shown in your screenshot is for creating the block and customizing what data is fed from the database into the block.  Under **Block settings** *Access*, you can set permission for all instances of the block.  In this case, the permission is *View published content*, which in nearly all cases both anonymous and authenticated users have, so this is not where you want to look.

Instead, I would check the block layout settings at `/admin/structure/block`.  Here, find the relevant blocks, click edit for each block, and check the permissions (are they set to be displayed by role?). If you do not see the blocks here, it's possible they are configured via Layout Builder, Panels, or some other module, so you will have to examine your site configuration to see how the blocks are being placed.